# Bootstrap 3 Modal parent page not opaque?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an MVC app with a Bootstrap Modal declaration in my _Layout.cshtml and I call with some Javascript which loads a MVC partial view into the modal. Everything seems to work fine except that the outer area of the modal is not grayed out showing the user that they can't click anywhere outside of the Modal. In other words the parent page looks like it's active and the Modal is just sitting on top of the parent page.

I've done some searching but I'm not finding anything I can try to get it to show the parent page as being disabled.

Here is my code in my _Layout.cshtml page.

```
@********  Bootstrap Modal - used with Partial Views  ************************@
<div id="modal-container" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content" id="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        // Attach modal-container bootstrap attributes to links with .modal-link class.
        // when a link is clicked with these attributes, bootstrap will display the href content in a modal dialog.
        $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
            $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
        });

        // Attach listener to .modal-close-btn's so that when the button is pressed the modal dialog disappears
        $('body').on('click', '.modal-close-btn', function () {
            $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
        });

        //clear modal cache, so that new content can be loaded
        $('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
        });

        $('#CancelModal').on('click', function () {
            return false;
        });
    });



    /***** Vertically center Bootstrap 3 modals so they aren't always stuck at the top ********/
    $(function () {

        function reposition() {

            var modal = $(this),
                dialog = modal.find('.modal-dialog');

            modal.css('display', 'block');

            // Dividing by two centers the modal exactly, but dividing by three
            // or four works better for larger screens.
            dialog.css("margin-top", Math.max(0, ($(window).height() - dialog.height()) / 2));
        }

        // Reposition when a modal is shown
        $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', reposition);

        // Reposition when the window is resized
        $(window).on('resize', function () {
            $('.modal:visible').each(reposition);
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Which Bootstrap version you're using? Ensure the Bootstrap JS & CSS file versions match each other, if you're insist to use current one try adding `<div class="modal-backdrop fade in" style="height: **;"></div>` (** = div height in pixel) or set `background-color` property in `.modal-backdrop` & `.modal-backdrop.fade.in` selectors.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check all of that but this a pretty new project. Should be Bootstrap 3.